# switch x axis numbers (low to high from high to low) Ex(1-5) = (5-1)

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeOa6.png)

Hi so I tried to do the code that was given when I looked up how to switch the xaxis numbers around but it didnt seem to work. If there are any ideas let me know! :D . I dont understand why this wont work I tried without the ax=gca but that didnt work either :D

Comment: What are you trying to do ? are you taking existing plot `axis` with `gca` ?

Comment: You can refer [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/multiple_figs_demo.html).

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: Stackoverflow is place where code is shared and others can run on their environments. Please provide language and other environment information

Comment: [ax.invert_xaxis()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.invert_xaxis.html?highlight=invert_xaxis#matplotlib-axes-axes-invert-xaxis) ?